# Automation with python and selenium - Frame name being changed on each access

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to do an automation with web selenium and I'm having a lot of problems with frames

Every time I access the site, the name and id of the frame I need is changed, my code in python and the html below:

Html Code:

[image]

```
driver.switch_to_frame('mainsystem')
driver.switch_to_frame('mainform')
espera = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
time.sleep(5)
frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(('name','URLFrame8749307'))
time.sleep(2)
frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(('name','mainform'))
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use partial name/ID taht starts with `'URLFrame'`

```
frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name^="URLFrame"]'))
```

Comment: Now it looks like he got it, but he's not finding the element I want
I need to go through 4 frames the element